# AMD w/ define() doesn't work in a particular case (create-react-app based app; webpack; babel)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, create-react-app

I have a React app (built using "create-react-app"), in which I integrated some legacy code that is using AMD. I have a lot of constructs, such as:

```js
define(["backbone", "basejs/app/AppUtils"],
function(Backbone, AppUtils)  {
    ...
```

Everything works OK out of the box in dev mode (e.g. "yarn start"). But something goes wrong in prod mode (e.g. "yarn build"), with errors such as:

```
index.html:1 ReferenceError: define is not defined
    at Module.2936 (XopsConstants.js:1:1)

XopsConstants.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

I understand that normally Webpack detects "define(...)", and removes the call "define", replacing with injection of the required lib. But this doesn't seem to happen in "prod"; hence the function still remains in the outputted code. Hence the error, that "define()" is not defined.

I looked thorough the "react-scripts" to try to understand what are the differences between the 2 cases. I observed that setting `NODE_ENV` to "development" or "production" seems to lead to the issue. I'm talking about [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/67b48688081d8ee3562b8ac1bf6ae6d44112745a/packages/react-scripts/scripts/build.js#L12) file/line.

I would really appreciate some hints that may help me while debugging.

For the moment I don't understand if the issue is caused by babel or by webpack.

### Update

After some tweaking, I could compare the outputted files. So for this original code:

```js
define(["jquery", "backbone"],
         function($, Backbone) {
    
    var AppInit = function() {
//      this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    };
    
    _.extend(AppInit.prototype, {
        
        initApp: function() {
            var originalBackboneSync = Backbone.sync;
            
            if (window.isWindowsApp) {
                var path = decodeURI(window.location.pathname);
                window.operationDomain = new NodeDomain("operation", path.substr(1, path.lastIndexOf("/")) + "lib/modules/node/OperationDomain");
```

The transpiled DEV version is:

```js
/***/ "./src/old-app/AppInit.js":
/*!**************************************************!*\
  !*** ./src/old-app/AppInit.js ***!
  \**************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

    var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;!(__WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_ARRAY__ = [__webpack_require__(/*! jquery */ "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"), __webpack_require__(/*! backbone */ "./node_modules/backbone/backbone.js")], __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__ = (function ($, Backbone) {
        var AppInit = function () {//       this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
        };
      
        _.extend(AppInit.prototype, {
          initApp: function () {
            var originalBackboneSync = Backbone.sync;
      
            if (window.isWindowsApp) {
              var path = decodeURI(window.location.pathname);
              window.operationDomain = new NodeDomain("operation", path.substr(1, path.lastIndexOf("/")) + "lib/modules/node/OperationDomain");
```

We can notice that the code is pretty similar AND there is no **define()**.

And the transpiled PROD version is this one:

```js
/***/ "./src/old-app/AppInit.js":
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony import */ var _home_poweruser_git2_xops_xops6_xops6_react_node_modules_babel_preset_react_app_node_modules_babel_runtime_helpers_esm_defineProperty__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__ = __webpack_require__("./node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/defineProperty.js");

define(["jquery", "backbone"], function ($, Backbone) {
  var AppInit = function AppInit() {//      this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  };

  _.extend(AppInit.prototype, {
    initApp: function initApp() {
      var originalBackboneSync = Backbone.sync;

      if (window.isWindowsApp) {
        var path = decodeURI(window.location.pathname);
        window.operationDomain = new NodeDomain("operation", path.substr(1, path.lastIndexOf("/")) + "lib/modules/node/OperationDomain");
```

I.e. we can see the offending "define()". Why? Where is the fork in the config for webpack and/or babel that seem to take into account NODE_ENV?

Answer (score 0):

Via trial and error, I deduced that this seems to be a bug triggered by the fact that I have constructs such as:

```js
                var requestResponse = {
                        url: ajaxOptions.url,
                        method: ajaxOptions.type,
                        data: ajaxOptions.data,
                        httpStatus: jqXHR.status,
                        error: data || jqXHR.statusText,
                        data: ajaxOptions.data
                      };
```

Observe the `data` key twice, that gives a linter warning: "no-dupe-keys" = there are duplicate keys.

My fix: via the reported compiler warnings I fixed such constructs. And then modified the linter config to prevent such mistakes:

```json
{
    "extends": ["react-app"],   
    "rules": {
        ...
        "no-dupe-keys": "error"
    }
}
```

I also opened this [bug](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/15594).